# Different measures of Christ's grace in Ephesians 4:7?

Tags: ephesians, pauline-epistles

Ephesians 4:7 ASV

> But unto each one of us was the ***grace given according to the measure of the gift of Christ***

Having said we are one spirit and one body

Ehesians 4:4 ASV

> ***There is one body, and one Spirit***, even as also ye were called in one hope of your calling; 5 one Lord, one faith, one baptism,

Does this mean we receive different measures of grace from Christ?.

Comment: According to this text we do.  However, I suspect it actually means "abilities" here.  See Rom 5:20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the text, grace is apportioned according to the work that is given to each person.

> But to each one of us grace was given according to the measure of
> Christ’s gift… 11 And He gave some as apostles, some as prophets, some
> as evangelists, some as pastors and teachers, 12 for the equipping of
> the saints for the work of ministry, for the building up of the body
> of Christ. – Eph 4:7-12

In the world, positions and responsibilities are assigned/awarded according to ability/achievement. In the body of Christ, however, everything is a gift from God, both the work and the grace with which to accomplish it. The measure of the one is directly related to the proportion of the other.

> However, since we have gifts that differ according to the grace given
> to us, each of us is to use them properly: if prophecy, in proportion
> to one’s faith… – Rom 12:6-8

Paul is a perfect example of his own teaching.

> For I am the least of the apostles, and not fit to be called an
> apostle, because I persecuted the church of God. 10 But by the grace
> of God I am what I am, and His grace toward me did not prove vain; but
> I labored even more than all of them, yet not I, but the grace of God
> with me. – 1 Cor 15:9-10